# How to Exclude a model from being part of the database when using MVC and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, paypal

I am currently writing a .NET MVC application using a SQL Server DB and Code First EF.  All has been going great and stackoverflow has been extremely helpful.  Unfortunately I have an issue I cannot solve and I can't find any help on the Internet.

I want to integrate with PayPal and I was following http://logcorner.com/asp-net-mvc-paypal-integration which seems fairly straight forward except that VS wants to create a database table for my PayPal model and I don't need or want it to.  I have added `[NotMapped]` in front of the class but now it generates this error:

> The type 'MyApp.Models.PayPal' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

I saw some other information about adding Ignore(lambda expression) in the `OnModelCreating()` method of my db context but that seems to be for excluding a column, not the entire class.

Any ideas?  I don't want a database table for every model in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default all the model will be created in database which is the part of your  `myAppEntities : DbContext` class and which properties type is `DbSet<>`.If you have decorated your model `MyApp.Models.PayPal` as `notmapped`attribute.

```
[NotMapped]
public class PayPal
{
//your all properties
}
```

Then remove `Dbset<PayPal>` properties from your class which is inherited form `DbContext` Class.

```
    public class MyAppEntities : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<PayPal> paypal { get; set; } //Remove this or comment this line
            ...
            ...
           //rest of your properties
    }
```

By doing so this won't be part of your database and you wont get this error.
( Explanation of this thing will cover a whole topic which i can't explain here).

Comment: This nailed it, thank you @Rajput. I didn't notice that the DbContext class had added **public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<myDBContext.Models.PayPal‌​> PayPals { get; set; }** at the bottom.

Comment: Marked as the answer and upvoted but apparently my rep is to low to have my upvote counted.  A sincere thank you though for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of the `[NotMapped]` attribute is correct offhand.  The issue is either that **(a)** you're attempting to scaffold while this attribute is in force, or **(b)** you're attempting to access the db in relation to this type at run-time.  That's when I saw this error during my test work (see later).

At the design end, the following would solve your problem *if* you are using auto-scaffolding (but see later):

1. Delete or comment out `[NotMapped]` on your PayPal-facing class.
2. Recompile.  (Due to latencies in MVC's introspection into the code,
       your past attribute will still be in force until you do this.)
3. Now do your scaffolding.
4. Now uncomment or re-add `[NotMapped]`.
5. Recompile again for the same reason as before.

There isn't much reason to auto-scaffold if that is where you're having problems, as you don't want to save your data so you don't need CRUD ops.  The example on your refsite uses nearly-empty controllers compared to what the IDE generates for you.

At the run-time end (that is, in your controller code), just make sure you never touch the db.  ***Definitely*** nothing like `db.SaveChanges();`  You shouldn't need to as I was saying; this is really a ViewModel and it exists solely to push data to PayPal.

---

To verify the problem and solution, I created an example MVC app, got the message you saw, took the design-time steps, then ran the app in a browser, got the problem message again, removed the db-facing code from my unmapped-class controller, and was able to have things work properly.  I didn't use the PayPal-facing class but a simpler one to save time, but there should be no difference in outcome.

I hope this resolves your problems.  --Ed

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.